# Hints to prove: total pre-order on X is isomorphic to a total order of sets of X

Tags: order-theory

I am wondering can I please get some hints on how to prove the following.

> total pre-order on $X$ is isomorphic to a total order of sets of $X$

**Note that**:

For example given $\{r_1 \lesssim r_2 \lesssim r_3 \}$:

- we can not have duplicate things: WRONG => $\{ \{ r_1 \lesssim r_2 \} < \{ r_3 \lesssim r_1 \} \}$
- we don't lose anything: WRONG => $\{ \{ r_1 \} < \{ r_3 \} \}$
- we don't have empty inner sets WRONG => $\{ \{ r_1 \lesssim r_2 \} < \{ r_3 \} < \{ \} \}$

**Notation:**
I used a single line to represent $a \lesssim b \lesssim c$ but that is generally not correct because in [total pre-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Total_preorders) we can have cycles. I meant a set of pair of relationships $a \lesssim b$.

**My attempt**:

To prove this we need a deterministic way of going from:
$$T= \{ r_0 \lesssim \dots \lesssim r_i \lesssim \dots \lesssim r_{i+j} \lesssim \dots \lesssim r_n \}$$
to (for example):
$$T'= \Big \{ \{ r_0 \lesssim \dots \lesssim  r_i \} < \dots < \{ r_{i+j} \lesssim \dots \lesssim r_n \} \Big \}$$
and the opposite direction.

For the forward direction, for each $r_i \in T$ we can map it to some set $s_k \in T'$ in a way that the result of this mapping is compatible with $T$. Because for all $(r_i \lesssim r_j) \in T$ then its one of two cases:

- $r_i$ and $r_j$ belong to two different sets $s_k, s_l \in T'$,
  $r_i \in s_k$ and $r_j \in s_l$ such that $s_k < s_l$. This happens
  when $r_i < r_j$ and ($<$) notation is equivalent of $r_i \lesssim
     r_j \wedge r_j \not \lesssim r_i$
- Otherwise they belong to the same set $r_i, r_j \in s_k$.

Conversely, we can take reconstruct $T$ from $T'$ in two steps:

- for all $s_k \in T'$, for each $(r_i \lesssim r_j) \in s_k$ yield a rule $r_i \lesssim r_j$
- for all $s_k, s_l \in T'$, for each $r_i \in s_k$ and $r_j \in s_l$ yield a rule $r_i \lesssim r_j$

And then summarize all the rules to create a total pre-ordered set such that $\bigcup T' = T$. The end result is compatible with $T'$ because for any $(r_i \lesssim r_j) \in T'$ its one of two cases:

- they belonged to two different sets: $r_i \in s_k$ and $r_j \in s_l$ and $s_k < s_l$. In this case $r_i < r_j$ (see above definition)
- they belonged to the same sets.

**Later thoughts:**

I think it's a weak isomorphism because we are enforcing a constraint for the isomorphism to be true.

Comment: *What* sets of $X$? Make this question understandable. Saying "we can represent things as sets" is ludicrous.

Comment: @TedShifrin I meant going from $a \lesssim b$ to $\{ a \} \lesssim \{ b \}$ for example.

Comment: Be explicit. What subsets of $X$? All? How? Singletons, yes. This is one of the vaguest questions I’ve ever seen.

Comment: @TedShifrin Not singletons only. We may have this as well: $\{r_3,r_6,r_7\} \lesssim \{ r_4  \} \lesssim \{r_2,r_8 \}$

Comment: @TedShifrin I added so much details.

Comment: A given totally preordered set need not be isomorphic (in the sense of order isomorphism) to a totally ordered set, for the same reason that a preorder need not be an order.  Are you trying to show that there is a *one-to-one correspondence* between total preorders on a set $X$ and total orders on *partitions* of $X$?  See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set

Comment: @leslietownes yes exactly. one-to-one. T/{\something} partition.

Comment: OK. It may help to consult https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preorder (section labeled "Preorders and partial orders on partitions") and refine your question based on what you see there. The Wiki link is not really a proof but a list of correct assertions that could make a template for a proof.  A "pure math" style proof would fill in those details with a good bit of symbols and unwinding of definitions.  Because your notation is somewhat unconventional, I wonder if this is arising in an applied context where something other than a "pure math" proof of every detail is desired.